# Large integers division error in python

Tags: python, largenumber

I'm doing some calculations with large integers in Python and I'm getting some weird results.

```
>>> 94970389L * 94958913L / 775920493L
11622692L
>>> 94970389L * 94958913L
9018284906627157L
>>> 775920493L * 11622692L
9018284906627156L
```

Why is there a difference between fourth line and sixth line ? It should be equal.

I'm using Python version 2.7.3 on linux pc 32bits

Comment: Rounding error. You can easily tell that the results should be different because the first set ends in 9 & 3 respectively, so you know the first product will end with a 7. The second set's least-significant digits are 3 and 2, so you know the second product will end in a 6. Thus, you know the answers are probably correct.

Comment: FYI, you don't have to type the Ls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remainder of your division is 1:

```
>>> 94970389L * 94958913L % 775920493L
1L
```

Remember, division of two integers in Python 2.x is an integer division by default, and the remainder is thrown away.

Comment: `from __future__ import division`